# The tag handler class for "c:url" (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.UrlTag) was not found on the Java Build Path

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

```
<c:url var="addAction" value="/user/add"></c:url>
```

> warning:The tag handler class for "c:url"
>   (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.UrlTag) was not found on the
>   Java Build Path

I have included the `JSTL` jar but still it gives same warning.
Is any other jar required?

Comment: <c:url var="addAction" value="/user/add"></c:url>   <c:forEach items="${listPersons}" var="person">  For these lines i am getting the above warnings

Answer (score 1):

You have to add standard.jar as well.

Comment: I added, but still warning is there

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the jar files into the correct directory?

They need to be stored in the lib folder in `WEB-INF` (`...WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/`).

You may have just stored them in the `WEB-INF` folder.